# Delete content from variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

My problem is, how can I delete some content from a variable? I just want to get the coordinates of my screens.

So I can get the content with `$screen1 = Get-WmiObject win32_desktopmonitor` but I don't know how to get rid of the rest of the content I don't need.

Here is the output:

```
DeviceID            : DesktopMonitor1
DisplayType         : 
MonitorManufacturer : 
Name                : Standardmonitor
ScreenHeight        : 
ScreenWidth         : 

DeviceID            : DesktopMonitor2
DisplayType         : 
MonitorManufacturer : 
Name                : Standardmonitor
ScreenHeight        : 1200
ScreenWidth         : 1920

DeviceID            : DesktopMonitor3
DisplayType         : 
MonitorManufacturer : (Standardmonitortypen)
Name                : PnP-Monitor (Standard)
ScreenHeight        : 1200
ScreenWidth         : 1920
```

I just need the screen height and width of DesktopMonitor2 and the other one I would save in a new variable.

I need this to open two browser screens in kiosk mode on different screens. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Rather than trying to remove something from an object, think of **what you want to keep**. Something like: `$screen1 | Where-Object Device ID -eq DesktopMonitor2 | Select-Object -Property ScreenHeight, ScreenWidth`

Comment: It might even be easier to keep the object as a whole: `$Screen2 = $screen1 | Where-Object Device ID -eq DesktopMonitor2` and use the properties when you need them, e.g.: `$Screen2.ScreenHeight`

Comment: Sounds like you need the `.` member access operator. If `$screen1` describes a variable containing an object with a `ScreenHeight` property, then `$screen1.ScreenHeight` will resolve to said properties value - so if you want to store the value itself in a new variable, you do `$screenHeight = $screen1.Height`

Comment: So thats my Point of state now; `$Screen = Get-WmiObject win32_desktopmonitor

$ScreenHeight = $Screen.ScreenHeight
$ScreenWidth = $Screen.ScreenWidth

$Screen1Width = $ScreenWidth | Select-Object -First 1
$Screen1Height = $ScreenHeight | Select-Object -First 1
$Screen2Width = $ScreenWidth | Select-Object -Skip 1
$Screen2Height = $ScreenHeight | Select-Object -Skip 1`. The thing from iRon with `Where-Object DeviceID -eq DesktopMonitor2` somehow doesn't work. If somebody has a clue why, I would be happy, because this would be the perfect solutio for me.

Comment: Then I would not have to do this with the `Select-Object -Skip1` and `-First 1`. And the Computer where this script will be running is a Laptop, so when it's open, this script doesn't work anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice that you're using an old version of Windows PowerShell.
<sub>(I recommend you to update to the latest version of Windows PowersShell 5.1 or even better: [PowerShell Core](https://aka.ms/pscore6) using[`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/07-working-with-wmi?view=powershell-7))</sub>

Anyways, for PowerShell 3.0, you should be able to do this:

```
$Screens = Get-WmiObject win32_desktopmonitor
$Screen2 = $Screens | Where-Object { $_.DeviceID -eq DesktopMonitor2 }
$Width2 = $Screen2.ScreenWidth
$Height2 = $Screen2.ScreenHeight
```